# How to call a JavaScript function in ActionScript 1?

Tags: javascript, actionscript

I wold like to know how to call a JavaScript function from ActionScript 1 and get the result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used AS1 for years but I used the old FSCommand in the past.

See a very detailed tutorial here:
http://www.moock.org/webdesign/flash/fscommand/
which is similar to http://forums.adobe.com/message/2701630

Another alternative here:
http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=8332

Thanks and good luck! :)